# Issues with Google Cloud Shell Tutorials: Options Hanging Except for Custom Image Override

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I'm experiencing issues with Google Cloud Shell tutorials and need assistance troubleshooting. Over the last 24 hours, I've observed and tested different scenarios with varying results with help from others in different geographic regions.

#### Scenario Description:

1. **Generic Google Cloud Shell Tutorial (Default Settings):** This setup hangs for most users at the tutorial initialization stage.

   - Parameters used:

     - `cloudshell_git_repo=https://github.com/spurin/cloudshell-troubleshooting`
     - `tutorial=tutorial.md`
     - `shellonly=true`
   - [Link to Cloud Shell](https://ssh.cloud.google.com/cloudshell/open?cloudshell_git_repo=https://github.com/spurin/cloudshell-troubleshooting.git&cloudshell_tutorial=tutorial.md&shellonly=true)
2. **Google Cloud Shell Tutorial with Default Image Specified:** Similar issues as in option 1 are observed.

   - Parameters extended with `cloudshell_image=gcr.io/cloudshell-images/cloudshell:latest`
   - [Link to Cloud Shell](https://ssh.cloud.google.com/cloudshell/open?cloudshell_git_repo=https://github.com/spurin/cloudshell-troubleshooting.git&cloudshell_tutorial=tutorial.md&shellonly=true&cloudshell_image=gcr.io/cloudshell-images/cloudshell:latest)
3. **Using a Custom Cloud Shell Image:** This option seems to work without issues.

   - Parameters extended with `cloudshell_image=gcr.io/graphite-cloud-shell-images/terraform:latest`
   - [Link to Cloud Shell](https://ssh.cloud.google.com/cloudshell/open?cloudshell_git_repo=https://github.com/spurin/cloudshell-troubleshooting.git&cloudshell_tutorial=tutorial.md&shellonly=true&cloudshell_image=gcr.io/graphite-cloud-shell-images/terraform:latest)

#### Observations and Questions:

- The issue seems specific to the default cloudshell image used in options 1 and 2, as option 3 with a custom image works fine.
- A few participants did not encounter any issues across all options, which adds to the confusion.

Has anyone else experienced similar issues or can provide insights into why the default options are hanging? Any troubleshooting tips or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

*Tagged:* `[google-cloud-shell]`